# two videos side by side

Tags: video, python-2.7, multimedia

I want to view two different videos in the same window. I can not find any library that would help me do that. i use pylab for displaying images in the same manner.
I will have a 3d matrix with the pixel values for each frame.
this is for a multimedia project.
I would also want to set the frames per second of each video too if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In order to play video streams you can use http://pymedia.org/tut/ , as for displaying two streams side by side may be you could create two "panels" inside a GUI application with tkinter (http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) or PyQt (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt).